# Register ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm trying to register ISecureDataFormat with Microsoft Unity. I tried to register it like this:

```
container.RegisterType<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>();
```

However I encounter the following error when I try to reach the class:

> The current type, Microsoft.Owin.Security.ISecureDataFormat`1[Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket],
>   is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type
>   mapping

Original code from Microsoft without DI that works look like this:

```
public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager,
    ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
    AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;
}

public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}

public ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> AccessTokenFormat { get; private set; }
```

Perhaps I need to use InjectionFactory or something but at the moment I'm stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got it to work:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(ISecureDataFormat<>), typeof(SecureDataFormat<>));
container.RegisterType<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>, SecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>();
container.RegisterType<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>, TicketDataFormat>();
container.RegisterType<IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>, TicketSerializer>();
container.RegisterType<IDataProtector>(
    new InjectionFactory(c => new DpapiDataProtectionProvider().Create("ASP.NET Identity")));
```

Comment: I would like to upvote this answer but can you advise the documentation for this code.